# When can JVM (or OS) close the file handler abnormally?

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm

My application is running on top of Apache Hama which is distributed computing framework implemented in java.

Multiple servers can issue the data pulling requests to the multiple machines. I use RPC in hadoop to make it server/client model.

When a machine receives data pulling request, it then opens the file and

I encountered the following error:

```
ERROR org.apache.hama.XXX:java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.size(FileChannelImpl.java:315)
    at org.apache.hama.FileHandler.openHandler(XXX.java:235)
    ...
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:959)
```

I use **RandomAccessFile** class to handle the very large file from a few GB to a few tens of GB.
The error message says the file handler is closed by the interruption. But it does not say exactly why.

The application code does not have any line of code that interrupts a certain threads. I suspect JVM or OS is invoking interuppt.

When can JVM (or OS) close the file handler abnormally?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/1161297/1085186

Comment: @StackFlowed that's helpful, thanks. However, my program does not have any line of code that (at least explicitly) invoke interrupts on a certain thread.

Comment: Unless you share your code how can we be sure of that ?