# Can a java thread be interrupted only by 'Interrupt()' function call?

Tags: java, jvm

I have an application written in java.

I use **RandomAccessFile** class to handle the very large file from a few GB to a few tens of GB. The error message says the file handler is closed by the interrupt.

```
ERROR org.apache.hama.XXX:java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.size(FileChannelImpl.java:315)    
...
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:508)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:959)
```

I have no line of code that explicitly call 'interrupt' on a certain thread. Where should I start taking a look to find the root cause of the interrupt?

Comment: Could be that interruped has a different context here. It's not Thread.interrupt but stream interrupt. Again, just maybe, I don't know.

Comment: I haven't worked with Hadoop's RPC API, but could it be that Hadoop has an automatic timeout configured, and that's what's causing the timeout? (Or maybe your service is shutting down? Looking at the code, that seems to be the only place the Handler is interrupted: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.0/org/apache/hadoop/ipc/Server.java#Server.0handlers)

Comment: [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ClosedByInterruptException.html) disproves my point. :(

Comment: You could attach a debugger to your JVM and set a method entry breakpoint on Thread.interrupt()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When can JVM (or OS) close the file handler abnormally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254637/when-can-jvm-or-os-close-the-file-handler-abnormally)

Comment: @the8472 That's a brilliant idea. Which debugger program can I use for it?

Comment: Have you tried googling it before asking me?

Comment: @the8472 sure, they say there are various tools for debugging jvm like jdb, visualVM and Btrace. But I don't know the best suited one for it. The debugger tool attached to IDE is also not a candidate for me.

Comment: So you already found options and asking me to recommend a specific one out of several? That's [offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO. If you run into problems when using any of those you can of course ask a question how to deal with it.

Comment: @the8472 oh please... This isn't a post, just a minor comment. Don't be so rigid.

Comment: Well, `interrupt` can be called indirectly. E.g. by calling `cancel(true)` on a `Future`…

Comment: The interruption may also bee part of Hadoop’s node management…