# Cannot contact : java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException while using GeckoDriver and Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm running tests using:
Selenium 3.11
Geckodriver v0.20.1
TestNG 6.9.8
Firefox 57 on Linux OS

I have 10 suites with 10-30 classes in each. Total duration time is about 16 hours. Webdriver gets created in beforeClass and get's quit in afterClass (using driver.quit()).

When I run tests using Chrome Driver, everything is okay and all the suites are executed completely.

But if I switch the driver to Firefox driver, only 3-4, or 5 suites are executed, and then I receive the following error:

```
Cannot contact : java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
Can't take a screenshot: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:14191
```

It appears in different steps and actions, the test just goes regularly and then 
this error appear:

```
2018-05-30 18:52:12.545 -         NavigationTree.executeNavigationCommand:87 [[treePasteItem]]
2018-05-30 18:52:15.018 -         Toastr.waitToastIsNotShown:51 
2018-05-30 18:52:17.130 -         NavigationTree.getRootNode:131 
Cannot contact : java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
Can't take a screenshot: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:14191
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-34-46.ec2.internal', ip: '172.31.34.46', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
2018-05-30 18:53:16.441 -       FAILED: RenameDeleteJobs_14
2018-05-30 18:53:16.441 - [LAST MESSAGE RECEIVED FROM THE TEST]
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:14191
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-34-46.ec2.internal', ip: '172.31.34.46', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.perform(RemoteWebDriver.java:611)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:638)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.perform(Actions.java:594)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$perform$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at exa.tags.framework.utils.Helper.moveFocusToElement(Helper.groovy:290)
    at exa.tags.framework.utils.Helper$moveFocusToElement$13.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at exa.tags.framework.utils.Helper.moveFocusToElement(Helper.groovy:298)
    at exa.tags.framework.utils.Helper$moveFocusToElement$12.call(Unknown Source)
    at exa.tags.framework.pages.navigation.NavigationTree.getNodeByName(NavigationTree.groovy:185)
    at exa.tags.framework.pages.navigation.NavigationTree$getNodeByName$4.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at exa.tags.framework.pages.navigation.NavigationTree.getNodeByPath(NavigationTree.groovy:204)
    at exa.tags.framework.pages.navigation.NavigationTree$getNodeByPath$9.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at exa.tags.framework.pages.navigation.NavigationTree.getNodeByPath(NavigationTree.groovy:223)
    at exa.tags.framework.pages.navigation.NavigationTree.selectNodeByPath(NavigationTree.groovy:232)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at exa.tags.suites.jobs.RenameDeleteJobsTest.RenameDeleteJobs_14(RenameDeleteJobsTest.groovy:756)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
    at org.testng.TestNG$run$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at exa.tags.runner.TestManager$_runTests_closure1$_closure4.doCall(TestManager.groovy:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:442)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2030)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2015)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2056)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at exa.tags.runner.TestManager$_runTests_closure1.doCall(TestManager.groovy:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:442)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2030)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2015)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2056)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at exa.tags.runner.TestManager.runTests(TestManager.groovy:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:206)
    at exa.tags.runner.TestManager.main(TestManager.groovy:38)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:14191
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:240)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:158)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:238)
    ... 116 more
```

I added memory info output but seems like there are still enough resources for JVM:

```
OS: Linux
    Version: 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 amd64
    Available processors (cores): 8
    Current directory: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ExaCLOUD_UI_tests_pipeline/branches/feature-E.6pdikdaolhhr.IE-Chrome/workspace/ExaTAGS/TagsRunner

    Currently allocated to the JVM: 2,249.5 Mb
    Free memory in JVM: 1,257.568 Mb
    Used memory in JVM: 991.932 Mb
    Max memory the JVM could reach: 3,250 Mb
    Total free memory: 2,258.068 Mb

    File system root: / 
    Total space: 102387.98046875 Mb
    Free space:30855.1953125 Mb
    Usable space: 30855.1953125 Mb
```

My question is: where to look for and what to add to debug info to investigate the reason of this happening?

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Cannot contact : java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
Can't take a screenshot: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:14191
```

...implies that a *checked exception was received by a thread when another thread interrupted it while it was blocked in an I/O operation upon a channel*.

### ClosedByInterruptException Class

[**`ClosedByInterruptException`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ClosedByInterruptException.html) is a checked exception which is raised when a thread interrupts another thread while it is busy/blocked in an I/O operation upon a channel. Before this exception is thrown the channel must have been closed.

It is worth to mention that, channel operations are pretty much bound to the *thread* doing the I/O operations. If this thread is interrupted the stream or the channel is closed due to IO safety issues.

Your code trials would have given us some more hints about what's going wrong but from the error stack trace it is evident one of the major issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Though you are using **Selenium v3.11.0** but your **JDK** seems to be **v1.8.0_45** which is pretty older.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u171**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.12.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.20.1**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Ensure GeckoDriver is present in the specified location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v60.0.1*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

### trivia

If the *AUT (Application Under Test)* is a multi-threaded application, you should look for `interrupt()` calls that might interrupt the thread doing the IO operations on the channel. If it is a web-application or some other kind of managed environment, where thread management isn't up to your application (like a Servlet / EJB Container), you should look for thread-safety violations. Another place to look is when the application is shutting down or when thread pooling is used (Servlet/EJB Container!). Then be aware of dynamic management of the pool size!

### References

You will find a detailed discussion in [**Why are we getting ClosedByInterruptException from FileChannel.map in Java 1.6?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161297/why-are-we-getting-closedbyinterruptexception-from-filechannel-map-in-java-1-6)

Comment: Still the same after updating all parts to latest versions (actually, those listed above). I also notised exot code 137. So Seems like there is an OOM issue and something kills the process