# Ant JUnit task failing due to a ClosedByInterruptException

Tags: java, junit, concurrency, ant, junit4

My JUnit tests are failing due to a **ClosedByInterruptException**, after finishing running a test it fails to write it's test report and just stops with the following exception:

```
    [junit] Exception in thread "main" Unable to write log file
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLJUnitResultFormatter.endTestSuite(XMLJUnitResultFormatter.java:197)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.fireEndTestSuite(JUnitTestRunner.java:860)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:579)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1205)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1021)
    [junit] Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    [junit]     at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    [junit]     at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:200)
    [junit]     at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFullyImpl(Channels.java:78)
    [junit]     at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFully(Channels.java:101)
    [junit]     at java.nio.channels.Channels.access$000(Channels.java:61)
    [junit]     at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write(Channels.java:174)
    [junit]     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    [junit]     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.FormatterElement$DelayedFileOutputStream.flush(FormatterElement.java:394)
    [junit]     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    [junit]     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    [junit]     at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    [junit]     at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.DOMElementWriter.openElement(DOMElementWriter.java:368)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.DOMElementWriter.write(DOMElementWriter.java:209)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.DOMElementWriter.write(DOMElementWriter.java:222)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.DOMElementWriter.write(DOMElementWriter.java:222)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLJUnitResultFormatter.endTestSuite(XMLJUnitResultFormatter.java:195)
    [junit]     ... 4 more
```

I am using **ant-junit-1.10.5-jar**.  The snippet for the method **endTestSuite** is:

```
        if (out != null) {
            Writer wri = null;
            try {
                wri = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF8"));
                wri.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n");
                new DOMElementWriter().write(rootElement, wri, 0, "  ");
            } catch (final IOException exc) {
                throw new BuildException("Unable to write log file", exc);
            }
```

My JUnit ant target looks like this:

```
    <junit dir="${test.path}/${test.dir}" fork="on" forkmode="once" haltonfailure="${junit.halt.on.failure}" outputtoformatters="true" printsummary="on" showoutput="true">

        <sysproperty key="junit.aspectj.dump" file="woven-classes" />
        <!--
        <sysproperty key="junit.cobertura.agent" value="${junit.cobertura.agent}" />
        -->
        <sysproperty key="junit.code.coverage" value="${junit.code.coverage}" />
        <sysproperty key="junit.debug" value="${junit.debug}" />
        <sysproperty key="cluster.link.primary.node" value="true" />
        <sysproperty key="net.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile" file="${test.path}/test-coverage/${test.type}/cobertura.ser" />
        <jvmarg line="${junit.debug.jpda}" />
        <jvmarg line="${junit.profile.agent}" />
        <!--
        <jvmarg line="${junit.cobertura.agent}" />
        -->
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx${junit.java.mx}" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dexternal-properties=${test.properties}" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" />
        <jvmarg value="-Duser.timezone=GMT" />
        <classpath location="${test.path}/test-coverage" />
        <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.path}/test-results/${test.type}">
            <fileset dir="${test.path}/test-classes/${test.dir}" includes="**/${test.class}.class">
                <exclude name="${test.excludes}" />
                <filename regex="${junit.test.excludes}" negate="true" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
```

Comment: Not sure if it can help you but still it should give you idea why exception is occurring at all and then you might find a good path... just a try... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161297/why-are-we-getting-closedbyinterruptexception-from-filechannel-map-in-java-1-6

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72384015/1672678 for possible explanation.