# Test with Spring annotations causes ClosedByInterruptException when executed in maven test run

Tags: java, spring, maven, unit-testing, junit

I have a test class which looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestClass.TestConfig.class)
public class TestClass{

    @Configuration
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "package.with.dummy.provider.and.aspect", includeFilters = { 
            @Filter(Aspect.class), @Filter(Provider.class) })
    public static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        CustomApplicationListener listener() {
            return new CustomApplicationListener ();
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    CustomApplicationListener listener;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        // Do something with the listener
    }    
}
```

When I run it with JUnit from Eclipse, it works just fine. But when the test is executed in my maven build/test cycle, it fails with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
     at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
[...]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [Path\To\Aspect\DummyAspect.class]; nested exception is java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:454)
[...]
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
     [java]     at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:220)
     [java]     at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.size(FileChannelImpl.java:327)
     [java]     at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.available(ChannelInputStream.java:128)
     [java]     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:421)
     [java]     at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:479)
     [java]     at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:445)
     [java]     at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54)
     [java]     at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
     [java]     at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:430)
```

I'd like to know the differences in executing tests from Eclipse vs from maven which may cause the observed situation to happen.

<s>**Update**
When removing `basePackages = "package.with.dummy.provider.and.aspect"` from the `@ComponentScan` annotation, everything works as expected! The package path is correct though. Now if someone could explain why this happens...</s>

**Update 2**
Well looks like it's even stranger. After some more tests I can confirm that the test passes *once* whenever I change the value of `basePackages`. After the first update where I removed the value and the test passed ran, it failed the text time and every time after that. I then tried to change the value to `package.with.dummy.provider.and`, removing one level, and it passed - once. Sounds like maybe some files generated by maven in the build and test process are not properly cleaned up, therefore the `@ComponentScan` finds and tries to read the files multiple times which causes the `ClosedByInterruptException`.

Comment: Good to refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161297/why-are-we-getting-closedbyinterruptexception-from-filechannel-map-in-java-1-6

Comment: Do you have Spring Tool Suite (3 or 4) installed in your Eclipse ? JUnit in Eclipse usually means there is a cycle supported by STS.

Comment: Check if some previous test calls Thread.currentThread().interrupt()

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, the solution is as below.

Now spock framework has support of JUnit 5, now you can run spock test cases with JUnit 5.

Upgrade your spock to latest version [**2.0-M1-groovy-2.5** (not released yet but we can use now for solution)]

And add below new dependencies to your project.

```
testCompile group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-engine', version: '1.5.2'
compile group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-commons', version: '1.5.2'
```

Now run your `gradle test` task, it will run both spock and JUnit5 test cases without failure.

Happy Coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Canatto Filipe check if your production or test code uses

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt()
```

If it does, you can clear the interrupted state of the thread with:

```
Thread.interrupted()
```

In our case it was failing at an attempted write using java.nio.file.Files.write
in one of the tests with:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:216)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFullyImpl(Channels.java:78)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFully(Channels.java:101)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels.access$000(Channels.java:61)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write(Channels.java:174)
    at java.nio.file.Files.write(Files.java:3297)
```

because the production code correctly responded to InterruptedException by interrupting the thread:

```
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

and this was also tested in one of the tests.
Now in corresponding test we additionally check that the thread was interrupted and clear the interrupted state at the same time:

```
    Assert.assertTrue(Thread.interrupted());
```

Before the change, it depended if this other test is executed before or after the test which failed.