# Maven throws java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException when running Junit4 tests

Tags: maven, junit4

I'm observing and try to find out the root of an java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException with maven. If I invoke *mvn clean package* locally on my machine the result will be a ClosedByInterruptException. On our Jenkins server the behaviour is not observable.

```
Tests in error: 
shouldGetPrivateInformationSheetPdf(com.example.MyTest):  java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
shouldGetCompanyInformationSheetPdf(com.example.MyTest): java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
shouldReportFakeDummyBuilderInToString(com.example.MyTest2): Scan interrupted
```

I can see that the error happens if an file will be open and read.

```
 shouldGetCompanyInformationSheetPdf(com.example.MyTest)  Time elapsed: 0.025 sec  <<< ERROR!
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at com.example.fixture.Fixture.havingInformationSheetPdf(Fixture.java:1335)
    at com.example.fixture.Fixture.havingCompanyInformationSheetPdf(Fixture.java:1282)
    at com.example.MyTest.shouldGetCompanyInformationSheetPdf(MyTest.java:194)
```

In the docu of ClosedByInterruptException I read. I'm not aware that Junit has a race condition.

> Checked exception received by a thread when another thread interrupts
> it while it is blocked in an I/O operation upon a channel. Before this
> exception is thrown the channel will have been closed and the
> interrupt status of the previously-blocked thread will have been set.

I'm using a virtual machine VMware Workstation 16 Player with Ubuntu 2020.04.

What I have done until now:

- I observed memory - which seems to be ok
- I changed processor core from 12 to 4.
- I added to maven some parameters to run with one thread etc.

The result is the same.
With Intellij I oberve the same behaviour.

If I'm using @Ignore the tests are running through.

Does anybody has an idea how I can fix the issue?

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72384015/1672678 for possible explanation, it might depend on the execution order of the tests depending on which one trigger Thread.currentThread().interrupt().